# Glassfish Hibernate JPA 2.0 Exceptions

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I am using Glassfish 3.1.1 and hibernate 3.6.5 with MySQL 5.1 + mysql-connector-java-5.1.6

Intermittently I get the following exception when I run or deploy my JSF2.0 and EJB3.1 based module

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [com.mysql.jdbc.TimeUtil], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

Well the resource keeps varying everytime, sometimes it is `org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$2` or `com.mysql.jdbc.profiler.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory` or `import.sql`

May be it has something to do with my config,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="XXXX" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/XXXXXX</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The properties configured in Glassfish connection pool are,

```
driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXX
portNumber: 3306
databaseName: XXXX
serverName: localhost
user: yyy
password: yyy
```

Could someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha.  Finally I found out the cause for the error.  It was a problem with Nebeans, which was always selecting the wrong version of JPA in persistence.xml.  So, I manually configured the persistence.xml as follows and it works fine now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="XXXX" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/XXXXXX</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```